# How to display two or more markers on the same location?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a question about the GOOGLE MAP API. If you have more than two data that share similar address, how do you show the Pins Drop on the same address?

*Example*

1. You have data such as the following:

   ```
   Name=>Ray | Address=>Melon Park, California, USA ; 
   Name=>John | Address=>Melon Park, California, USA ; 
   Name=>Steve | Address=>Melon Park, California, USA
   ```
2. You want to display 3 Pins Drop for the similar address on Google Map.

Comment: i am looking for the same, how to display two or more markers on the same location..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548920/google-maps-api-v3-multiple-markers-on-exact-same-spot

Answer (score 1):

The post linked above has some good advice.  Your options are really:

1. Offset the markers slightly, so instead of displaying them all on the same  they are all on really close to each other.  Just add add or subtract small delta to each of them.
2. Use different icons for each location.  If you know the maximum number of markers that could overlap (like 4?) at the same location, you could make your own rotated icons, so instead of pointing "down" in the typical teardrop shape they could point left, right, or up.
3. Handle the data overlap in your infowindow / UI.

Answer (score 1):

Adding small delta will work like this (this script is written in PHP):

```
$random_num_lat = .00065 * mt_rand(1, 10); // delta to the lat value added
$random_num_lng = .00065 * mt_rand(1, 10); // delta to the lon value added

$lat=$row['lat']+$random_num_lat;
$lon=$row['lon']+$random_num_lng;

//now in loop it will be three `enter code here`marker display seperate to each other

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$name</b><br/>$desc1');\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using a "spiderfier" to "spiderfy".

There is a GoogleMaps v3 Spidifier available [here](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) ([demo](http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo.html)).

Leaflet.js can also load GoogleMaps v3 and has a beautiful clustering spidifier available [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) ([demo](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.388.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Note: Following is a more of hack than a solution:

Write an algorithm that checks for repeated coordinates in array.

When a duplicate is found, add a small value such as 0.000001 to the found coordinates. 
Note that the smaller the value the more you have zoom in to see the difference.