# Get latitude and longitude that is 5 metres away of a latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps-api-3, location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google maps API V3 - multiple markers on exact same spot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548920/google-maps-api-v3-multiple-markers-on-exact-same-spot)

I have a lat and lng of a location and i am going to plot many markers on that point. How do I prevent the markers from overlapping? Say 5 metres away from each marker.