# Try to slightly change geocode of multiple markers on exact same location

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a similar problem with [Google maps API V3 - multiple markers on exact same spot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548920/google-maps-api-v3-multiple-markers-on-exact-same-spot). I have read [@
DzinX 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548920/google-maps-api-v3-multiple-markers-on-exact-same-spot#comment25531290_9143850) and try to use it. But it seems my lat and lng cannot use "+". But when i try "*", it worked. The datatype of lat and lng is float(tried double and decimal also). Any reason why?

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  lat = locations[i][0];
  lng = locations[i][1]

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat*2, lng),  icon: 'images/markers_red.png'
                });
      markers.push(marker);
      marker.setMap(map);

    }
```

Comment: So your issue is trying to add two floats together, not to do with the Google Maps API?

Comment: "The datatype of lat and lng is float(tried double and decimal also)." I don't think so. JavaScript does not have any of those types. It has a `number` type and a `string` type among others. What do `typeof lat` and `typeof lng` evaluate to?

Comment: @Jared any idea how to add two floats together?

Comment: @MichaelGeary  i mean in database

Comment: JavaScript doesn't know anything about your database. It doesn't know what types you use in the database. All it knows is what's actually sent down to the browser.

Comment: If `*` does what you expect, but `+` doesn't, it may likely mean that you don't have `number` values, but `string` values instead. Check `typeof lat` and `typeof lng`.

Comment: Programming languages (such as JavaScript) are pretty forgiving and will usually convert the variable's type to the one required for the calculation. You can force a variable to be a float by calling `parseFloat(x)`.

Comment: You could also be dealing with objects not floats. The Google Maps API will sometimes convert your floating latitudes and longitudes into an API-friendly object. Double-check you're dealing with floats.