# How to handle multiple makers at same location in Google Maps API?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I know there are some answers on this already, but I havne't been able to figure it out. I'm using Google Maps with Advanced Custom Fields in WordPress.

I pull the locations from the ACF and this then generates the maps.

However, the some of the locations are the same; so the infowindow only shows one title and the others are totally hidden.

I would be fine if the markers are slightly spreak apart.

I would also be okay if the infowindow could include all of the titles of all of the posts that are in the same location.

Can anyone help?

This is the current code:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAArX_FiOGh9BVSA-VaKWxf3BTjV82plXfzb-h9w4F1dGZTQrT8wxSgksN4vLUdfoCX3U-gz7r_GPkm2A" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");
google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.16");
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

/*
*  render_map
*
*  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $el (jQuery element)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function render_map( $el ) {

// var
var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

// vars
var args = {
    zoom        : 16,
    center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

// create map
var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);

// add a markers reference
map.markers = [];

// add markers
$markers.each(function(){

    add_marker( $(this), map );

});

// center map
center_map( map );

}

// create info window outside of each - then tell that singular infowindow to swap content based on click
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content     : ''
});

/*
*  add_marker
*
*  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $marker (jQuery element)
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

// var
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

// create marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position    : latlng,
    map         : map
});

// add to array
map.markers.push( marker );

// if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
if( $marker.html() )
{

    // show info window when marker is clicked & close other markers
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        //swap content of that singular infowindow
                infowindow.setContent($marker.html());
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    // close info window when map is clicked
         google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            if (infowindow) {
                infowindow.close(); }
            });

}

}

/*
*  center_map
*
*  This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function center_map( map ) {

// vars
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// loop through all markers and create bounds
$.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

    bounds.extend( latlng );

});

// only 1 marker?
if( map.markers.length == 1 )
{
    // set center of map
    map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
    map.setZoom( 16 );
}
else
{
    // fit to bounds
    map.fitBounds( bounds );
}

}



/*
*  document ready
*
*  This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded)
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   5.0.0
*
*  @param   n/a
*  @return  n/a
*/

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.acf-map').each(function(){

    render_map( $(this) );

});

    });

    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple markers in same location, I suggest using [**MarkerClusterer**](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#markerclusterer).

As discussed,

> `MarkerClusterer` is a client side utility library that applies grid-based clustering to a collection of markers. It works by iterating though the markers in the collection that you wish to cluster and adding each one into the closest cluster if it is within in a minimum square pixel bounds.

Sample usage and demo can be found in GitHub -
[Marker Clusterer – A Google Maps JavaScript API utility library](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) and solutions given in this SO post - [Google maps API V3 - multiple markers on exact same spot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548920/google-maps-api-v3-multiple-markers-on-exact-same-spot) might help too.